# Asift and openCV?

Tags: opencv, sift, asift

Does opencv allows to use ASIFT ?

http://www.ipol.im/pub/algo/my_affine_sift/

The creator published the c++ so I believe it wouldn't be so hard to implement it into opencv

Comment: I don't think this is the SIFT implementation used. Most effort is into implementing patent free alternatives to SIFT/SURF - such as ORB

Comment: who would downvote such a question?????

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by

> Does opencv allows to use ASIFT ?

At this moment, ASIFT is not available in OpenCV directly, but it should be a no-brainer to connect the code provided by the ASIFT authors to OpenCV. Probably all you'll have to do is to convert the OpenCV cv::Mat to some specific image format, by accessing Mat::data pointer.

If you are worried about licensing terms, you should contact the ASIFT authors. OpenCV is free to use/modify/redistribute/sell, under a BSD licence. And it seems that it is the same for ASIFT.

And if you are talking about integrating the code into OpenCV, and sending a patch to the dev guys, there is a guide on how to do it here http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/CodeSubmissions and here http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute and here http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/CodingStyleGuide . I (and many others) strongly encourage you to do it! It seems to be an important addition to OpenCV.

Comment: By now, there's a [Python script in OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/d579f080936308a9f1aa10463eb1c8d991676cfc/samples/python/asift.py) that implements A- variants of many feature matching algorithms that are present in OpenCV, thus obtaining ASIFT, ASURF and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The 2022 update is that ASIFT is in OpenCV v3.4 and higher.

Examples for the latest stable (v4.6):

- [C++](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.6.0/samples/cpp/asift.cpp)
- [Python](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.6.0/samples/python/asift.py)